# Jquery toggle information on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a button when on click, changes its HTML and the HTML of another element. I have it working, but it only triggers once. I am trying to get it to toggle between fahrenheit and celsius when clicked. I have tried two separate if statements, and toggle method but not sure if I attempted it the right way.

Here is my code.

```
  var c = $("button:contains(°C)");
  var f = $("button:contains(°F)");

  $('.temp-switch').on('click', function () {
    if (f) {
      $('.temp').html((Math.round(data.main.temp * 10) / 10) + " °C");
      f.html("°C");
    } else {
      $('.temp').html(Math.floor(data.main.temp * 1.8) + " °F");
      c.html("°F");
    }
  });
```

Here is the HTML to prevent any confusion.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card p-2">
      <div class="row">
        <h3 class="header mx-auto">Local Weather</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row icon-box mx-auto">
        <img class="weather-icon mx-auto">
      </div>
      <div class="row info-box mx-auto">
        <div class="location mx-auto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row info-box mx-auto">
        <div class="desc mx-auto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row info-box mx-auto">
        <div class="temp mx-auto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row info-box mx-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center mx-auto temp-switch w-50">°F</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: maybe add the html that comes with your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `f` and `c` variables outside of the function, so they won't change. You need to check inside the function:

```
var data = {
    main: {
    temp: 32    
  }
}
$('.temp-switch').on('click', function () {
    var type = $("#type").data('type');
    if (type == 'f') {
      $('.temp').html((Math.round(data.main.temp * 10) / 10) + " °C");
      $("#type").html("°C").data('type', 'c');
    } else {
      $('.temp').html(Math.floor(data.main.temp * 1.8) + " °F");
      $("#type").html("°F").data('type', 'f');

    }
  });
```

HTML

```
<button id="type" data-type="f">
  °F
</button>
<button class="temp-switch">
  Switch
</button>
<span class="temp"></span>
```

This is probably the best way to do it, using a data-attribute (per Munteanu's answer.) https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/5238187p/1/

Comment: @stackoverfloweth, thanks, if the OP is downvoting this then I should never have answered. :p

Comment: Shouldn't `"button:contains(°C)"` be `"button:contains('°C')"`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus, probably, but then again, that's hardly the biggest issue.

Comment: This is screwed up on multiple levels. This is changing the value of something that it's checking for and then expecting the value to stay the same.

Comment: No I am not downvoting anything. I put my variables in the function but that does not change anything. I am pretty sure I already tried it earlier too.

Comment: That's it. All I needed was .length. Do you mind explaining why that is necessary?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan That's why it was a comment.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, what was a comment?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set methods to get f & c on click of the event handler. Then Make it change on click of a condition.

```
 var c = $("button:contains(°C)");
 var f = $("button:contains(°F)");

  $('.temp-switch').on('click', function () {
    if (f) {
      $('.temp').html((Math.round(data.main.temp * 10) / 10) + " °C");
    } else {
      $('.temp').html(Math.floor(data.main.temp * 1.8) + " °F");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it triggers once because you never change the `f` and `c` . So for example when the page loads you set them according with your dom query.

I personally would use a custom data attribute something and change it on each switch click.

Example of what i think is a better way to do it:

the HTML:

```
<div class="temp-switch" data-has-celsius="true"></div>
```

THE JS:

```
$('.temp-switch').on('click', function () {
    var celsius = $(this).data('hasCelsius') === "true" ? true:false;
    if (!celsius) {
      $('.temp').html((Math.round(data.main.temp * 10) / 10) + " °C");
      $(this).data('hasCelsius', true);
    } else {
      $('.temp').html(Math.floor(data.main.temp * 1.8) + " °F");
      $(this).data('hasCelsius', false);
    }
  });
```

Of course you need to modify to make it work with your DOM.

Easier fix on your code:

Just move `c` and `f` on the `click` event.

Example:

```
$('.temp-switch').on('click', function () {
  var c = $("button:contains(°C)");
  var f = $("button:contains(°F)");
  if (f) {
    $('.temp').html((Math.round(data.main.temp * 10) / 10) + " °C");
    f.html("°C");
  } else {
    $('.temp').html(Math.floor(data.main.temp * 1.8) + " °F");
    c.html("°F");
  }
 });
```

Comment: Upvote because you gave me the idea of using `data` attributes :)

Comment: Thank you,I think it is a better idea, because that way all the logic is related to that specific element, instead of having a global object keeping the state of it

Comment: Yep, the other fix (moving `f` and `c` inside the function) actually doesn't work because the buttons are being changed at the same time as they are being checked.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your variables c and f will never update because they are outside your click listener.

consider using a class that you toggle instead of selecting elements every time, as in the long run it will be more efficient.

```
 var btn = $('button'),
     switch = $('.temp-switch');

  switch.on('click', function () {
    if (switch.hasClass('farenheight')) {
      $('.temp').html((Math.round(data.main.temp * 10) / 10) + " °C");
      btn.html("°C");
      switch.removeClass('farenheight');
    } else {
      $('.temp').html(Math.floor(data.main.temp * 1.8) + " °F");
      btn.html("°F");
      switch.addClass('farenheight');
    }
  });
```

in my example you would need to update your html to add farenheight as a class to your switch if it starts in fareheight

Answer (score 0):

You were checking the `contains` condition only once, you need to move it into the click handler & also the `contains` always returns object you need to check length to see if it has matched any element.
See below code

```js
$(function(){
data={main:{temp:14}};

  $('.temp-switch').on('click', function () {
    var c = $("button.temp-switch:contains(°C)");
    var f = $("button.temp-switch:contains(°F)");
    
    if (f.length) {
      $('.temp').html((Math.round(data.main.temp * 10) / 10) + " °C");
      f.html("°C");
    } else {
      $('.temp').html(Math.floor(data.main.temp * 1.8) + " °F");
      c.html("°F");
    }
  });
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="card p-2">
      <div class="row">
        <h3 class="header mx-auto">Local Weather</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row icon-box mx-auto">
        <img class="weather-icon mx-auto">
      </div>
      <div class="row info-box mx-auto">
        <div class="location mx-auto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row info-box mx-auto">
        <div class="desc mx-auto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row info-box mx-auto">
        <div class="temp mx-auto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row info-box mx-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center mx-auto temp-switch w-50">°F</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

move the declaration of your `c` and `f` variables to within the scope of your `click`

```
$('.temp-switch').on('click', function () {
  var c = $("button:contains(°C)");
  var f = $("button:contains(°F)");

  if (f) {
    $('.temp').html((Math.round(data.main.temp * 10) / 10) + " °C");
    f.html("°C");
  } else {
    $('.temp').html(Math.floor(data.main.temp * 1.8) + " °F");
    c.html("°F");
  } 
});
```